# Question concerning Presburger arithmetic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, presburger-arithmetic

Context: Presburger arithmetic is the theory $\tau$ of structure $$ A = (\mathbb{N},0,1,+,\{c|\cdot\}_{c\in\mathbb{N}})$$ where for each integer $c > 1$, the unary predicate c|n holds if and only if n is divisible by c. Recall that $\tau$ has quantier-elimination.

The first part is to show that suppose a set $S \in \mathbb{N}$ is *ultimately periodic* if there exist positive integers $n_0$ and $p$ such that for all $n > n_0$, $n \in S$ iff $ n + p \in S$. Show that any quantifier-free formula that mentions a single variable $x$ defines an ultimately periodic subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Afterwards we should be able to use this result to show that there is no formula on free variables $x$, $y$ and $z$ that defines the multiplication relation $M = \{(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{N}^3: ab = c\}$ on the structure $A$.

I'm completely lost on this question and I cannot see a relation on the two parts of the question. I have read the post here [Presburger arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211149/presburger-arithmetic) but don't think it is too helpful. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The connection between the two parts is that the set of squares, $\{a^2:a\in\mathbb N\}$ is definable using the predicate $M$ but is not ultimately periodic.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I see! In this case do you have a clue of showing part 1?

Comment: I think part 1 should follow directly from quantifier-elimination, by induction on quantifier-free one-variable formulas.  But before doing that, check that "Recall that $\tau$ has quantifier-elimination" is really true; I think the vocabulary should also include $\leq$.

Comment: More precisely, the absence of $\leq$ from the vocabulary doesn't affect the questions much, but it does affect the claim of quantifier-eliminability.  I see no way to express $(\exists z)\,x+z=y$ without quantifiers in the given vocabulary.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you for your comments! The definition of Presburger arithmetic is given specifically as context and the fact that it has quantifier-elimination is proven previously so it is indeed true.

Comment: So how does that proof eliminate quantifiers from $(\exists z)\,x+z=y$ using only the specified vocabulary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, the unions, intersections and complements of ultimately periodic sets are again ultimately periodic. Since a quantifier-free formula is a boolean combination of atomic formulas, all we have to do is to prove the following claim :

> **Claim** Atomic formulas in one variable define ultimately periodic sets.

Up to equivalence, there are of two kinds of atomic formulas in the variable $x$ :

1. $x + n = m$ for $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$.
2. $c \mid (x + n)$ for $n, c \in \mathbb{N}$.

Atomic formulas of kind 1. define singletons (or the empty set if $n>m$, or the whole set if $n=m$), which are clearly ultimately periodic.
Atomic formulas of kind 2. define a ultimately periodic set with period $p = c$ because if $c \mid (x + n)$, then $c \mid (x + n + c)$. $\square$

Hence, every quantifier-free formula in a single variable defines a ultimately periodic set.