# Is the set of prime numbers first-order definable in $(\mathbb{N}, +)$?

Tags: logic, model-theory

The clearly intuitive answer is no. But I'm unsure of how to prove this, as there are no nontrivial automorphisms of $(\mathbb{N}, +)$, so the standard method doesn't work. What is the correct approach here?

Comment: Some helpful vocabulary: the natural numbers with addition is called Presburger Arithmetic and the first-order definable subsets are called semilinear sets (a generalization of eventually periodic sets to multiple dimensions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definable sets in $(\mathbb{N};+)$ are all [eventually periodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic#Presburger-definable_integer_relation) - this follows from [the usual quantifier-elimination (in an expanded language) argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2211227/28111) used to show the completeness of Presburger arithmetic - so the answer to your question is negative (and we can similarly use this to [rule out](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2192703/28111) the existence of a definable pairing function and similar constructions). But indeed this takes more work than a simple automorphism construction, and I'm not aware of any proof that doesn't go through some form of QE.